# Improve code readability, give python script bit more elegance

Tags: python, if-statement, refactoring, switch-statement

What are some code structuring/programming techniques to avoid this:

```
  if url.netloc  == "www.youtube.com" or "youtu.be" or "soundcloud.com or //
  "instagram.com" or "vine.co" or ETC ETC
     do XYZ
```

Comment: I do not think that means what you think it means. That is always True

Comment: Your code is subtly very incorrect. Assuming `url.netloc` does not equal "www.youtube.com", Python will go on to the next part of the conditional (after the first `or`), and evaluate "youtu.be" as a *boolean*, which will **always** be True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest, I guess, would be:

```
xyz_targets = ('www.youtube.com', 'youtu.be', ...)
if url.netloc in xyz_targets:
    doXYZ()
```

Or even:

```
actions = {'www.youtube.com': doXYZ,
                   'youtu.be': doXYZ,
                   ...
                   }
actions.get(url.netloc, doNothing)()
```

Or any variant on a similar idea which parses a config file for building `xyz_targets` or `actions`

Answer (score 5):

Following line

```
url.netloc == "www.youtube.com" or "youtu.be" or "soundcloud.com" or "instagram.com"
```

is like following:

```
(url.netloc == "www.youtube.com") or ("youtu.be") or ("soundcloud.com") or ("instagram.com")
```

and it always yield `True` because non-empty string is treated as truth value if used as predicates.

Use `in` instead as follow:

```
if url.netloc in ("www.youtube.com", "youtu.be", "soundcloud.com", "instagram.com", ..):
```

Alternatively use can use `or`, but it requires you to repeat `or url.netloc ==` multiple times.